# Drop str in a data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm loading a df from a csv that has some infinite values ( or so I guess). I don't want to change the csv file ( since theyre inputs to my program )

So when I load this specific file as following:

```
blocked2 = pd.read_csv(file8, usecols=[1,2,3,4])
blocked2.columns = names1
blocked2.head(), blocked2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 863708 entries, 0 to 863707
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Time     863708 non-null float64
LP       863708 non-null float64
HP       863708 non-null float64
Icomp    863708 non-null object
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 26.4+ MB
```

I'm interested on Icomp column. I tried plotting it and I saw a problem with a certain str values

```
plt.plot(blocked2.Icomp)
plt.show()
TypeError: 10.20147 is not a string
```

which is weird because this is a column of current ( ampères) values so it should all be floats.

looking at the csv files, I found certain values written as 
24.12088000
âˆž
âˆž

So I took a look at these values in the loaded dataframe and I get

```
15907
15.908
9.569441
15.00891
24.12088000
15908
15.909
9.574703
15.02067
*∞*
15909
15.910
9.574703
15.03243
*∞*
15910
15.911
9.574703
15.02067
*∞*
```

I got infinite values and they're a str type. My question is: Is there anyway I can find these str values and drop them from the dataframe ? Since I'll receive a lot of these CSV files and the infinite values could not be at the same position !

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert to numeric via [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html). Then use [`np.isfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) and [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) to filter out non-finite or non-numeric data respectively. Here's a demo:

```
s = pd.Series([32.32, -np.inf, 'inf', 'asdfa', -324.42, np.inf])

s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
s = s[np.isfinite(s) & s.notnull()]

0     32.32
4   -324.42
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following;

First

```
blocked2.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan,inplace=True)
```

then

```
blocked2.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

or

```
blocked2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I have not run this code myself, but something on these lines should work.

Comment: Since my infinite is not a np.inf this command wont replace the values. So it didn't work :(